# Match layout width to height

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have a `LinearLayout`, I set the width to `match_parent`. How can I match the height to the width to get a square layout?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/card_layout"> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can try this in activity: `int width = ll.getWidth();ll.getLayoutParams().height = width;ll.requestLayout();`

Answer (score 2):

To achive this you need to get width of your `@+id/linearLayout` programatically

```
LinearLayout mLinearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
int screenWidth = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
int screenHeight = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;

mLinearLayout.measure(screenWidth, screenHeight);
int layoutWidth = mLinearLayout.getMeasuredWidth();
```

And then set width values as height

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mLinearLayout.getLayoutParams();
params.height = layoutWidth;
mLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

You can also do this like @balaji koduri showed in `OnGlobalLayoutListener`

Answer (score 0):

Do it programmatically -

```
LinearLayout mLinearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mDialogLayout.getLayoutParams();
params.width = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
params.height = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
```

if you want other size -

```
params.width = 200;
params.height = 200;
```

Comment: This will set width and height of the view to width of the display. But layout may be seted to a half of screen width. It would be better to get width of the layout and set it as hight

Comment: Yes. But you can also set any size

Comment: In that case My first case will work. If you want margin you can -20 or 10dp pixel from total width.

Comment: Imagine the situation, you have a layout with width of 400 px, but you it is calculated by the system (you set `math_parent`). Your display has width of 800 px. In case of your firs answer you will set layout width and height to 800 px, but in reality you need to set them to 400 px.

Comment: Yes. In landscape mode it will not work.I need to set it by calculating minimum size between height and width. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

        layout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) layout
                                .getLayoutParams();
                        params.height = params.width;
                        layout.setLayoutParams(params);
                        layout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                                null);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your custom layout with overrided onMeasure

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
}
```